# Access remote folder with credentials in Ruby

Tags: ruby, remote-access, credentials

in Sinatra I'm generating an excel file and I should copy it to some remote folder with credentials.

Does anyone have idea how to access folder which are credentials restricted?

Thank you

Comment: How should you copy the folder? Any Idea what the remote destination provides ?

SSH, FTP, SFTP,. ....

Comment: Just FileUtils.mv. Should be possible, right?

Comment: Depends on your definition of remote then....

Comment: I got an address like this: \\remote-folder

Comment: Can you give more detail on what this "remote service" is? For example, if you're using AWS S3 storage then you could use a bucket policy.

Comment: Remote folder (not service) is just a folder on remote server. For example *192.168.0.0\some-folder*. But credentials are needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used a Sambal if anyone need this.